# Web service Outbound Gateway over SSL (.cert + user/password)

Tags: web-services, certificate, spring-integration, keystore, ws-security

I am working with Spring Integration and I would like to know if it is possible to secure the input/output produced via MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway in any way.

My structure:

Request Channel --> gateway --> Response channel

---

**UPDATE III**

- Security is HTTPS user /password
- Validation with certificate

Now, I simplified my logic. I am trying to configure the Wss4jSecurityInterceptor but in other way. From Spring WS documentation, I saw this example:

```
<bean id="wsSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="securementActions" value="UsernameToken"/>
    <property name="securementUsername" value="Ernie"/>
    <property name="securementPassword" value="Bert"/>
    <property name="validationActions" value="Signature"/>
    <property name="validationSignatureCrypto">
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.support.CryptoFactoryBean">
        <property name="keyStorePassword" value="123456"/>
        <property name="keyStoreLocation" value="classpath:/keystore.jks"/>
    </bean>
</property>
</bean>
```

Adapted to my Java configuration:

```
@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor wss4jSecurityInterceptor() throws IOException, Exception{
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor interceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
    interceptor.setSecurementActions("UsernameToken Encrypt");
    interceptor.setSecurementUsername("https user");
    interceptor.setSecurementPassword("https password");
    interceptor.setValidationActions("Signature");
    interceptor.setValidationSignatureCrypto( signature().getObject() );
    return interceptor;
}

public CryptoFactoryBean signature() throws IOException{
    CryptoFactoryBean trustStore = new CryptoFactoryBean();
    trustStore.setKeyStoreLocation( new ClassPathResource("security/keystore.jks") );
    trustStore.setKeyStorePassword( "keystore_password" );
    return trustStore;
}
```

This is quite frustrating but I am getting a new error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: validationSignatureCrypto is required
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
... 58 more
```

---

**UPDATE II**

In my second approach, I changed my configuration to @Bean methods. At this moment, I just configured user / password without success but I need to use my .cert file to connect to the server.

```
@Bean
public CallbackHandler passwordCallbackHandler(){
    SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler handler = new SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler();
    Properties users = new Properties();
    users.setProperty("user1", "pass1");
    users.setProperty("user2", "pass2");
    handler.setUsers(users);
    return handler;
}

@Bean 
public ClientInterceptor wsSecurityInterceptor(){
    XwsSecurityInterceptor xws = new XwsSecurityInterceptor();
    xws.setPolicyConfiguration(new ClassPathResource("securityPolicy.xml"));
    xws.setCallbackHandlers(new CallbackHandler[]{
        passwordCallbackHandler()
    });
    return xws;
}
```

My securityPolicy.xml:

```
<xwss:SecurityConfiguration xmlns:xwss="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/xwss/config">
<xwss:RequireUsernameToken passwordDigestRequired="false" nonceRequired="false"/>
</xwss:SecurityConfiguration>
```

Getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
... 72 more
```

---

**UPDATE I**

I integrated:

- spring-integration-ws
- spring-ws-security

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableWs
  @EnableIntegration
  public class ConfigWS {
  @Bean
    public MessageHandler wsOutboundGateway() throws Exception {

      MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway gw =new MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway(myprovider, 
              jaxb2Marshaller(), 
              jaxb2Marshaller());
      gw.setOutputChannelName("responseChannel");

      SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler spvch = new SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler();
      Properties users = new Properties();
      users.setProperty("user", "pass");      
      spvch.setUsers( users );    

      XwsSecurityInterceptor xws = new XwsSecurityInterceptor();
      xws.setSecureRequest(true);
      xws.setSecureResponse(true);
      xws.setPolicyConfiguration( new ClassPathResource("securityPolicy.xml"));
      xws.setCallbackHandler( spvch );

      gw.setInterceptors( xws );
      gw.afterPropertiesSet();

      return gw;
  }
  ....
  }
  ```

I am getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.callback.PasswordValidationCallback$PasswordValidator
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 50 more
```

- How can I configure security securityPolicy.xml in order to
  authenticate against a server certificate.
- Is SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler the solution required to
  work with a server certificate? Maybe I have to use other handler.
- My certificate provider gives me a .cert file. Thus, I generated
  .keystore with keytool of Oracle but I have no idea about how to
  include this certificate in my configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Integration WebServices module is fully based on the [Spring WS](http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/). So, just follow with its giudeline how to configure WSS on the [client side](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#security).

There is just enough to inject `XwsSecurityInterceptor` or `Wss4jSecurityInterceptor` to the `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>`.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I was trying to make it work but I couldn't.  I edited my question to clarify my new scenario.

Comment: But I need and Interceptor if I just want to send user/password and install a .cert for my client? How can I configure this authentication?